# Bootstrap switch target incorrect

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a list of bootstrap switches. I have two categories: Facebook and Twitter. Each of these categories can have multiple switches. My issue is the only switch that works correctly is the first switch in each list. So I can toggle Facebook's first switch correctly and Twitter's first switch correctly.

Where the problem comes in is if I introduce a second switch. The problem is that the second switch incorrectly toggle's the first switch. (The same goes for any switch introduced after that - so Twitter's 5th switch will still toggle the first Twitter switch).

I attach the event handlers here:

```
if (typeof($.fn.bootstrapSwitch) != 'undefined') {
  $('form.bootstrap-switch-form').each(function () {
    var $form = $(this);
    var $checkbox = $form.find('input[type=checkbox]');
    $checkbox.bootstrapSwitch({
      size: $form.data('switch-size') || 'small'
    }).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, data) {
      $form.submit();
      $checkbox.bootstrapSwitch('toggleReadonly');
    });
    $form.on('ajax:complete', function (e) {
      $checkbox.bootstrapSwitch('toggleReadonly');
    });
  });
}
```

At the end of this function everything is linked correctly (I walked through the debugger and everything points to the correct place).

Each form is rendered to the page using rails:

```
<%= form_for automation, remote: true, html: {class: 'bootstrap-switch-form automation-switch', autocomplete: 'off'} do |f| %>
  <% if automation.has_automationable? %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :automationable_id, value: automation.automationable_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :automationable_type, value: automation.automationable_type %>
<% end %>
<%= f.hidden_field :retailer_id, value: retailer_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :category, value: category %>
<%= f.check_box :status, {id: category}, 'active', 'inactive' %>
<% end %>
```

It renders to the page as: [image]
Now, when I click on the second switch (or any switch for that matter) and put a debugger statement in the click handler for the "switchChange" event, and I look at the event.target, it's actually pointing to the first switch. Any thoughts on getting this to point to the correct place?

Also, just for clarification, when I hover over the second switch in the chrome console it is selecting the correct form. When I click on it, the debugger statement fires and "this" in that case is pointing to the incorrect checkbox / form.

**Update**

Turns out if I click the "on" side of the switch, the click handler works correctly for the correct switch. If I hit the "inactive" side (the side which is black) the handler points to the first switch in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, turns out each switch has to have a unique ID. Each label for twitter was id="twitter". I updated this so each label has a unique ID, id="twitter0", id="twitter1", etc. All fixed.